# How to update Backbone urls to get new data while keeping the same parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, url-routing

## The Problem

I have a collection that requests tasks from my api with its url set to /api/tasks/. I want to be able to get different tasks depending on the date and the context (work, home, ect.). When browsing to a url with different parameters, the collection updates its url with the extra parameters and fetches new data.

To facilitate this I've created two widgets, a calendar widget and context selector. A link in the calendar would point to `year/xxxx/month/xx/day/xx` and a selector link might point to `context/work` for example. I click a date, and I'd navigate to `myapp.com/tasks/#year/2012/month/09/day/25`. Now I want to see a different context but clicking results in my url changing to `myapp.com/tasks/#context/work` removing the date I was just at!

## The Solution

- I need to keep the old parameters like the date segment while adding a new ones like the contest.
- Additionally, I need to update parameters already in the url rather than tacking on new ones (e.g. changing `myapp.com/tasks/#year/2012/month/09/day/25/context/work` to `myapp.com/tasks/#year/2012/month/09/day/25/context/home` instead of `myapp.com/tasks/#year/2012/month/09/day/25/context/work/context/home`).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.. You could write a method which pulls the URL apart (ie window.location.hash.split('/')) and then rebuilt it from there right?

Comment: I thought of that, but my problem is when the link triggers the router the uri doesn't contain the old segments. If I visit `#context/work` I no longer have `#year/xxxx/month/xx/day/xx` to split and rebuild with.